# Compile a python app with external config.py that we can edit

Tags: python, configuration

I am trying to understand how to use a `config.py` file with a very basic application that allows the `config.py` file to be outside the compiled .exe application.

Here is my file structure.

`/ config.py`

`/ sayhello.py`

[sayhello.py]

```
import config as config

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print (config.CHARACTERS['PLAYER_1'] + ", I'd like for you to meet " + config.CHARACTERS['PLAYER_2'] + ".")
    print (config.CHARACTERS['PLAYER_2'] + ", this is your cousin " + config.CHARACTERS['PLAYER_1'] + ".\n")
```

[config.py]

```
# Define player names
CHARACTERS = {
    'PLAYER_1': "Abby",
    'PLAYER_2': "Billy"
}
```

I run the script in Visual Studio Code and the output looks like this.

```
Abby, I'd like for you to meet Billy.
Billy, this is your cousin Abby.
```

I run `pyinstaller sayhello.py` and I have a build / dist of the application. I execute `sayhello.exe` and the output is as expected, fantastic.

```
Abby, I'd like for you to meet Billy.
Billy, this is your cousin Abby.
```

Where is the `config.py` file for me to edit so I can change the characters name?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to locate `configparser` and found a working solution.

[sayhello.py]

```
from configparser import ConfigParser

parser = ConfigParser()
parser.read('config.ini')

player_one = str(parser.get('CHARACTERS', 'PLAYER_1'))
player_two = str(parser.get('CHARACTERS', 'PLAYER_2'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print (player_one + ", I'd like for you to meet " + player_two + ".")
    print (player_two + ", this is your cousin " + player_one + ".\n")
```

[config.ini]

```
[CHARACTERS]
PLAYER_1 = Abby
PLAYER_2 = Billy
```

I also found `auto-py-to-exe` which enabled me to add my `config.ini` file to my build.  The file got renamed to `config.py`.  I am able to open `config.py` into notepad, edit the names, safe, run, and names are updated as expected.

If there is an even better way to do it, I'd love to learn.